# Difference between padding and margin?

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what's the difference between padding and margin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823848/whats-the-difference-between-padding-and-margin)

Well, what's the difference? I haven't really understand it...

Comment: You should really try the search function, look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823848/whats-the-difference-between-padding-and-margin

Comment: Please look at the related question when you ask one. This was the first one in the list when you entered your title : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823848/whats-the-difference-between-padding-and-margin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At it's simplest, padding = inside spacing, margin = outside spacing.

Try it.

```
<div style="border:1px solid red;padding:8px;margin:8px;width:200px;">TEST</div>
```

The width of this element will be 2 (border) + 16 (margin) + 16 (padding) + 200 (declared width) for a total 234px.